# Where did Ayn Rand get the idea for Directive 10-289?

Tags: inspiration, ayn-rand, atlas-shrugged

I believe Ayn Rand got the idea for Directive 10-289 from witnessing the start of the Russian Revolution. She was 12 years old and had a bird's eye view of what was happening in Petrograd- where she was born and where the revolution started. So, the 10 represents the month of October and 289 (2x8+9) the day the revolt began. Directive 10-289 translates to October 25, 1917.

Is there evidence to support or refute this theory?